# Xpath or cssSelector for displaying current time

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWqDe.png)I am trying to get current time with either cssSelector or xpath.
I am able to get curren time using: `.is-today` as cssSelector directly in date picker.
Can we call current time or current time plus certain minute using cssSelector or xpath?

As image show today's date has been capture with `.is-today`

html is

```
<div class="listContainer svelte-ux0sbr” xpath=“1”>
<div class="item  svelte-bdnybl" xpath="1">09:05 AM</div></div>
```

Comment: need to see HTML, share it here in text format

Comment: @cruisepandey could you please look at the image

Comment: HTML please, that image does not contain HTML